# Url Rewrite issue in codeigniter and IIS 8.5

Tags: php, codeigniter, iis, url-rewriting

Here is my **web.config** file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Rewrite to index.php" enabled="true">
                    <match url="index.php|robots.txt|images|test.php" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Rewrite CI Index" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" ignoreCase="true" negate="false" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="bnrmcrz" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="css|js|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|htm|html" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php/{R:0}" logRewrittenUrl="false" />
                </rule>            
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I need a way to make the URL case insensitive as well as get rid of index.php from it.

When I give "**localhost/testProj**", it works fine. The next time I try to enter "**localhost/TESTproj**". it displays page not found. What I actually want is, irrespective of the way the folder name is provided, if it is spelled the same, it should redirect me to the same folder.

Please help me fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

as your post i can guess your controller name is `testProj`. So when you try to access `TESTproj` this is not an exist controller.  So Codeigniter through the `404 Error`.

So if you want to access `TESTproj` define this in `routes.php` file.

```
$route['TESTproj'] = 'testProj';
```

Comment: testProj is the folder name (main codeigniter folder). I have not specified my controller as it is set as defaultController. Basically, if m right.. the routes can be set only from the controller name onwards. Correct me if wrong.

Comment: so check spelling of your URL  and `base_url` too

Comment: Spelling is fine. What I want is....with the above rules...the URL "http://localhost/bnrmcrz"....gives me the application's login page. I can perform all the operations thereafter. But, when I'm trying to access the same application again but with the URL "http://localhost/BNRMCRZ" or any URL with a different case combinations as compared to the first (i.e. http://localhost/bnrmcrz).....it gives me an error saying "404 error...page not found". I actually need it to redirect to the same application irrespective of the letter case used in the URL. I can get exactly the place m going wrong.

Comment: you can define in that `$route['404_override'] = '';`

Comment: i already have $route['404_override'] = '' in my routes.php file.

Comment: i dont understand why it is working in the first place and when i change even the case of a single character it gives the 404 error. is there anything wrong wid my URL Rewrite??